# How do I remove ALL trailing whitespaces from ALL XML Node values using C#?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I am trying to write a generalized C# .NET code to check every XML node's value in a XML file for trailing whitespaces and remove them. I tried the PreserveWhiteSpace. But that did not work. Please advise.

```
<Sample>
<Item>
<Value>BatchID             </Value>
<Details>RecipeID              </Details>
</Item>
<Summary>Test data</Summary>
</Sample>
```

Comment: Check out String.Trim(). It removes all leading and trailing white-space characters.

Comment: Excuse my adding of a tag, but the first answer was well received

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will try them. I wanted specific nodes to be checked. So GetElementsByTagName helped :)

Answer (score 8):

You can use Linq2Xml

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(filename);

xDoc.Descendants()
    .Where(x => !x.HasElements)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(x => x.Value = x.Value.TrimEnd());

xDoc.Save(filename);
```